# Merging multiple areas to a range

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I want to select multiple cells in different areas and have them in one range object
eg select A1:A2 and A4:A5 , with CTRL+mouse, and have this in one range obejct.

I have tried this, and the item object does contain first A1:A2 and next A4:A5, but it isnt combined in the rng object

```
Sub FindMultiple()
Dim rng As Range
 For Each Item In Selection.Areas
    If rng Is Nothing Then
     Set rng = Item
    Else
     Set rng = Union(rng, Item)
    End If
  Next Item
End Sub
```

Comment: `Selection` is already the range you want, so just `Set rng = selection`

Comment: Beside what Rory writes: Code works for me.

Comment: I suspect it's what ever comes *after* this that is causing the confusion...

Comment: @Rory - Thanks for your quick reply, but it is not quite right.
Set rng = selection only get A1:A2 and not A4:A5

Comment: Are you sure that you have selected A1:A2 *and* A4:A5 at that moment?

Comment: I tried this in your loop (removing everything else) to test it and it shows the 2 areas. `Debug.Print item.Address` if that helps. But it does seem pointless since you are just building an identical selection.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time. I was doing too much debugging.
When i looked at rng in Watches, i only saw 2 values, so i was convinced it failed. but in a for-each, debug.print showed all of them.